# Create new Read Only user on DB2 on the whole database

Tags: db2, permissions, users, read-only-database

I am an oracle/sql server DBA having limited knowledge in IBM DB2. We have DB2 9.7 fp4 running on AIX 6. I would like to create a new user and grant him READ only privilege on a particular database. Please help!

Thanks & Regards
Mohammed

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no *read only* privilege on a database in DB2. You will need to grant `SELECT` privileges on specific tables, preferably via a role to avoid doing this multiple times.

1. Create a new database role, e.g. `create role readonly`.
2. Grant `SELECT` privileges on the required tables to that role: 
   `grant select on myschema.mytable to role readonly`.
3. Create a new user in the operating system, e.g. `# mkuser newuser`.
4. Grant the role to the user: `grant role readonly to user newuser`.

Note that the new user will likely need to change the initial password before he or she can connect to the database.

Comment: Perfect, mustaccio! Thank you so much! :)

Comment: Kudos to the use of roles. Much easier than trying to just grant priveleges to IDs directly.

Comment: What if we there is a request for multiple tables or a complete schema having 100+ tables?

Comment: Obviously, you'll need to include multiple `grant` statements in your process. It's quite easy to generate a script for that by selecting from `SYSCAT.TABLES`.